# Error messages on devise fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, devise

This is my code for a devise user , i have two types of users in the application .How do i display error messages besides the fields that they arise in . As you can see , i have used devise for the users.I have been using  `<%= f.error_notification %>` for displaying the errors but devise isn't showing it . All i see is "Please review the problems below" . Still learning on devise error views , any help on the same would be much appreciated .

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>  

   <div class="reg-gray-box fl">


                  <ul class="reg-form">
                      <li>
                          <%= f.input :email, :label => "Email Address", :placeholder => "Email", :required => false, :autofocus => true, input_html: { class: 'wh-txt-box' } %> 
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <%= f.input :password, :label => "Password", :placeholder => "Password", :required => false, input_html: { class: 'wh-txt-box' } %> 
                      </li>                         
                      <li>
                          <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In", :class => 'big-blue-btn' %> 
                      </li>  
                     <li>
                    <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name), :class =>'link' %>
                   </li>                                            
                  </ul>



    </div>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code to human-readable form.

Comment: Thanks.  I had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` line under this one `<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`.
Like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>  
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  ...
```

I would recommend prior asking the question to appeal to documentation first, specially in [such well](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb) documented cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one it will display the error messages.

Just add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: Can you re-format your answer and tell where should i be posting it ?